# Route resolver is not working for nested Observables in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

Code for route resolver:

```
  resolve() {
    return this.myService.activeReleases$;
  }
```

Below is the code for observable in the 'myService'. I have 2 streams here. reloadData$ is the stream which I am using to reload the data. I have added 'startWith(0)' so that the observable will start emitting when it's called.

```
private readonly reloadData$ = new Subject<void>();

    activeReleases$: Observable<ActiveRecords[]> = this.reloadData$
        .pipe(
          startWith(0),
          tap( () => console.log('Triggered reload')),
          switchMap( () => this.http.get(this.URL)
            .pipe(
              tap( () => console.log('Triggered getting records')),
              map((values: ActiveRecords[]) => {
                console.log('hi')
                return values;
              }),
              catchError(e => of(e)),
              ))
    );

    reloadData() {
        this.reloadData$.next();
    }
```

I can see the log statements I have mentioned above when I hit the url in browser but somehow the route is not resolving and I am seeing a blank page. However if I remove the 'this.reloadData$' observable then it works fine. Can't figure out what might be the issue.

I have created a dirty example if stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ugvvrc

If you click on the link 'Go to test page', nothing happens.

Would appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Any errors in the console

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka No there are no errors in console. Even it prints the log statements in the code. Page goes blank as it's not able to resolve this observable

Comment: do you see 'Triggered getting records' log after the navigation starts?

Comment: @Andrei yes I do. Even I see the log (hi) inside the map

Comment: can you also add the part where you are declaring `reloadData$`? What have you assigned to it and what is it's type?

Comment: @nash11 oops there was an error in variable naming while I was creating the question here. I have updated the question. 'reloadData$' is a Subject here

Comment: If you'll upload a sample project reproducing this than you'll get answers real quick

Comment: @benshabatnoam I have created an example in stackblitz and updated the question. Please take a look and suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to add `take(1),` to your pipe.

What this `take` operator does is it completes the observable after taking the `n` times you've passed it, in our case just the first one.

[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kbsln6)

```
import { ..., take } from 'rxjs/operators';

activeReleases$: Observable<ActiveRecords[]> = this.reloadData$
        .pipe(
          startWith(0),
          take(1),
          tap( () => console.log('Triggered reload')),
          switchMap( () => this.http.get(this.URL)
            .pipe(
              tap( () => console.log('Triggered getting records')),
              map((values: ActiveRecords[]) => {
                console.log('hi')
                return values;
              }),
              catchError(e => of(e)),
              ))
    );
```

NOTE: I don't know why this is a *must* in your situation but it works. (it looks like an angular's bug to me)

Comment: Yes, it works after adding the take operator but not sure why it's the case. Anyway thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure why this is happening either. glad to help. if you'll get an understanding as why this is happening I'll be glad to here. cheers